# Natbib error when using options

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have a TeX file like this

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{webofc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}   % Web of Conferences font
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} %% needed for advanced table manipulation
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

\begin{document}

....

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ACOc}
\end{document}
```

If I use `\citet{}` shows, e.g. `(Author?)[3]`. When using `natbib` options, like `[square]` or `[numbers]` it does not compile because it tells that the option is not recognized. I have also tested `plain` bib style instead of `plainnat` with the same result.
I do not know if the problem is some incompatibility with another package or with the doc style.
I would like to use `\citet{ref}` so it shows `Smith et al.[3]` format.

Thank you very much for the help

Regards

Comment: You can't generate author-number formatted citation call-outs with the `plainnat` bibliography style. Are you committed to using the `plainnat` style, or are you free to use another bibliography style?

Comment: References section should be as IEEEtran or similar with numbers, e.g., [3] Smith ......Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I know of no bibliography style that generates citation call-outs of the form "[3] Smith".

Comment: I do not know if I explained well. In the References Section of the paper (at the end) with the number [3], but the \citet{} command the name of the author and the number `Smith et al. [3]. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `elsarticle-num-names` bibliography style? It'll create the desired type of citation call-out. However, I don't know if the formatting of the bibliographic entries will meet your needs. (Coming to think of it, you haven't told us anything yet about how the bib entries should be formatted...)

Comment: I would like to have the flexibility of `natbib` that allows selecting how is the call-out by choosing `\cite, ` or `\citet`, Is that possible?

Comment: With `natbib`, `\cite` is an alias for `\citet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you get is `Option class for package natbib`.  (Next time please include it to your question.)

That means that your used package `webofc` already called package `natbib` with options, not including `square`.

To be able to pass your wished option to package `natbib` use the command

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square}{natbib} % option package
```

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{Wurm2004,
  author = {Wurm, Florian M.},
  doi = {10.1038/nbt1026},
  file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/sille/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Unknown - Unknown - R E V I E W.pdf:pdf},
  journal = {Nature Biotechnology},
  number = {11},
  pages = {393--398},
  title = {{Production of recombinant protein therapeutics in cultivated mammalian cells}},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/nbt1026},
  volume = {22},
  year = {2004}
}
@misc{obs,
  title  = "Titre", 
  author = {Joe Doe},
  year   = {2017},
  url    = {https://www.reallylongurl.fr/aaaa/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/ccccccc-ccccc_ddddddddd?eeeeeeeeee=125784.pdf}
}
@ARTICLE{AD.Smith2001,
  author    = {Arthur D. Smith},
  title     = {A simple model of LaTeX References.},
  journal   = {Journal of LaTeX},
  year      = {2001},
  volume    = {100},
  pages     = {1--10},
  number    = {3},
  keywords  = {LaTeX models; biology},
  doi       = {10.1115/1.1372322},
  publisher = {Cambridge},
  url       = {http://link.aip.org/link/?PBY/321},
}
@article{stacey1999,
  TITLE   = "Learning the Algebraic Method of Solving Problems",
  JOURNAL = "The Journal of Mathematical Behavior",
  VOLUME  = "18",
  NUMBER  = "2",
  PAGES   = "149--167",
  YEAR    = "1999",
  ISSN    = "0732-3123",
  DOI     = {10.1016/S0732-3123(99)00026-7},
  AUTHOR  = "Kaye Stacey and Mollie MacGregor",
  url     = {https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?q='Learning+the+Algebraic+Method+of+Solving+Problems'&btnG=Search},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[twocolumn]{webofc} % webofc

\PassOptionsToPackage{square}{natbib} % option package <================
%\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}   % Web of Conferences font
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} %% needed for advanced table manipulation

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-\do.\do+\do\n\do\l\do\o}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can pass `square` to `natbib`. However, the use of `\citet{}`does not provide the name of an author and the ref number together.

Comment: I wanted to achieve the correct rendering of `\citet` or `\citep`. Do you know a way to do it? I am not sure if it because of the .cls or not. Thank you for your help.